# Printing RDLC report from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, rdlc

Need some help printing RDLC report from my ASP.NET application. 
The report is loaded into Report Viewer control dynamically, then printed using javascript window.print().   The problem is the report is being printed with vertical scrollbar.  Plus, the bottom part of the report is getting cut off.  If I increase the height of the ReportViewer control, I end up with 2 blank pages before the actual report and one blank page after, and the bottom part is still getting cut off...
This is the html for Report Viewer page:

```
<body onload="printThisPage();">
     <form id="controlForm" name="reportForm" runat="server">
     <rsweb:ReportViewer Width="800px" Height="1200px" ID="ReportViewer1"  runat="server"  
        ShowCredentialPrompts="False" DocumentMapCollapsed="True" ShowDocumentMapButton="False" 
        ShowFindControls="False" ShowPageNavigationControls="False" 
        ShowParameterPrompts="False" ShowPromptAreaButton="False" 
        SizeToReportContent="True" ShowExportControls="False" 
        ShowPrintButton="True" ShowRefreshButton="False" ShowToolBar="False" 
        ShowZoomControl="False" BorderStyle="None" style="OVERFLOW: visible" 
        >
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </form>
```

I've been fighting with this for days..  Help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Print Button into the report RLDC. You should enable the 'ShowToolBar' property.

```
ShowToolBar="True"
```